# Apple Mach-O Linker Error on device XCode 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7.1

Hello i've recently upgraded to XCode 5.1 and suddenly my app throws a lot of errors when building on the Device (Iphone 5S), when I use the simulator everything works fine even on IOS 7.1, the error is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

In my build setting in Architectures and Valid Architectures I have only armv7, if I leave Standard Arquitectures the message is the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
```

Please I need help, I've tried everything already and cannot continue developing my app.
Thank you very much

Comment: I'm also having the same problem and none of the answers given so far seem to help;  libz.dylib is already in, Build Active Architecture Only is already set to No, and there's no frameworks missing from what I can see. I'm even trying the basic test app that cocos builds for you and it's the same thing. Is there anywhere that lists what SHOULD be linked, so that I can sompare?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project-> Build Phases- > click on the + sign below.
Search for libz.dylib in ios version and add it.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are using a defined function, but the linker cannot find the implementations of those functions. This is like having a slip of paper telling you where in a library to find a book, but the book is missing or moved somewhere.

Check to make sure that you are linking against all of the needed frameworks and that all of your source files are set to be built in the project settings.

Answer (score -1):

Go into your projects build settings under the *Architecture* heading. Change **Build Active Architecture Only** to **No**.

[image]